# Searching in SQL field WHERE LIKE %$user_id%

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a small problem.

I have my table as follows:

**tbl_groups**

```
id (int) | teacher_id (int) | student_ids (text)
------------------------------------------------
1        | 14               | 2015,2016,2017
2        | 35               | 15,16,17
3        | 14               | 631
```

`student_ids` will get filled by a PHP array using `implode()`.

However, when I execute the following query to search the group's id by a student id:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `tbl_groups` WHERE `student_ids` LIKE '%15%'
```

I get row 1 and 2 returned. This happens because `student_ids` "15" will be searched for, and "2015" contains "15" so it will also return it.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Storing values as csv  is very bad database design. You should redesign it. in the meanwhile you can use [find_in_set()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: If you only want to return the row where the ID IS 15, why not use `WHERE 'student_ids' = 15`?

Comment: try this if you want to match id if start with 15. SELECT `id` FROM `tbl_groups` WHERE `student_ids` LIKE '15%'

Comment: Please use @BerndBuffen solution. it will work in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **FIND_in_SET** like this:. it will return a value > 0 if it in the set.

```
SELECT `id` FROM `tbl_groups` 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('15',`student_ids`);
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT  FIND_IN_SET('15','15,16,17');
+------------------------------+
| FIND_IN_SET('15','15,16,17') |
+------------------------------+
|                            1 |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT  FIND_IN_SET('1','15,16,17');
+-----------------------------+
| FIND_IN_SET('1','15,16,17') |
+-----------------------------+
|                           0 |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT  FIND_IN_SET('17','15,16,17');
+------------------------------+
| FIND_IN_SET('17','15,16,17') |
+------------------------------+
|                            3 |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is worth reconsidering your database structure, instead of the layout you have suggested above consider having a table as follows

groups
id | teacher_id

student_group
student_id | group_id

You can then create a relationship where the group belongs to a teacher (One to Many) and a Many to Many relationship on student to group table allowing many students to be a member of many groups.

This will then allow you to query for groups containing a student by their ID more reliably.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (attention for performance if you have a large table: if you have an index on student_ids, probably it will not be used.  Anyway using LIKE '%xxx%' use it only with "scan" and not with "seek" ):

```
SELECT `id` FROM `tbl_groups` WHERE CONCAT(',',`student_ids`,',') LIKE '%,15,%'
```

Comment: The find_in_set function is better to do this : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set